# MySQL: selecting rows where a column is null

Tags: mysql, null

I'm having a problem where when I try to select the rows that have a NULL for a certain column, it returns an empty set. However, when I look at the table in phpMyAdmin, it says null for most of the rows.

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid = NULL
```

Empty set every time.

A lot of places said to make sure it's not stored as "NULL" or "null" instead of an actual value, and one said to try looking for just a space (`userid = ' '`) but none of these have worked. There was a suggestion to not use MyISAM and use innoDB because MyISAM has trouble storing null. I switched the table to innoDB but now I feel like the problem may be that it still isn't actually null because of the way it might convert it. I'd like to do this without having to recreate the table as innoDB or anything else, but if I have to, I can certainly try that.

Comment: MyISAM has no trouble storing null. The semantics of NULLs themselves should be independent of engine.

Answer (score 609, accepted):

SQL NULL's special, and you have to do `WHERE field IS NULL`, as NULL cannot be equal to anything,

<strike>including itself (ie: NULL = NULL is always false).</strike>

See `Rule 3` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules

Comment: It is Unknown - Not false. SQL uses three valued logic.

Comment: NULL = NULL is not really FALSE - it's NULL again. But it's not TRUE either, so IF(NULL = NULL) won't execute.

Comment: see also @obe answer: SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;  -> 1, 1, 0

Comment: Not only is null not equal to anything, it's not not-equal to anything, either.  In other words, `select * from foo where bar <> "abc"` will *not* return rows where bar is null. That threw me for a loop today. The docs call `<>` the "not equal to" operator, but really it's the "is equal to something other than" operator.

Answer (score 95):

```
SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 49):

As all are given answers I want to add little more. I had also faced the same issue.

Why did your query fail? You have,

```
SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid = NULL;
```

This will not give you the expected result, because from [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html)

> In SQL, **the NULL value is never true in comparison to any other value, even NULL.** An expression that contains NULL always produces a NULL value unless otherwise indicated in the documentation for the operators and functions involved in the expression.

Emphasis mine.

> To search for column values that are `NULL`, you cannot use an `expr = NULL` test. The following statement returns no rows, because **`expr = NULL` is never true for any expression**

## Solution

```
SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid IS NULL;
```

To test for `NULL`, use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators.

- [operator IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) tests whether a value is `NULL`.
- [operator IS NOT NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null) tests whether a value is not `NULL`.
- [MySQL comparison operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 27):

There's also a `<=>` operator:

```
SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid <=> NULL
```

Would work. The nice thing is that `<=>` can also be used with non-NULL values:

`SELECT NULL <=> NULL` yields `1`.

`SELECT 42 <=> 42` yields `1` as well.

See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Answer (score 12):

Info from http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp:

> 1) NULL values represent missing unknown data.
>
> 2) By default, a table column can hold NULL values.
>
> 3) NULL values are treated differently from other values
>
> 4) It is not possible to compare NULL and 0; they are not equivalent.
>
> 5) It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison
>   operators, such as =, <, or <>.
>
> 6) We will have to use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead

So in case of your problem:

```
SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid is null;
```

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue where query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'column' WHERE 'column' IS NULL;
```

returned no values.
Seems to be an issue with MyISAM and the same query on the data in InnoDB returned expected results.

Went with:

```
SELECT * FROM 'column' WHERE 'column' = ' ';
```

Returned all expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when converting databases from Access to MySQL (using vb.net to communicate with the database).

I needed to assess if a field (field type varchar(1)) was null.

This statement worked for my scenario:

```
SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE [field name] = ''
```

Comment: If that worked for you, the default for your varchar(1) is '' rather than null, therefore unrelated to this question.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the code with this one
it will work

`SELECT pid FROM planets WHERE userid IS NULL`

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights