# MySQL - Selecting rows with null columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, isnull

How can I select any row that contains empty or null column?

I'm  trying to run a check on my table, in which I want to see if any of my rows contain a column that doesn't hold a value..

example table: demo

```
+----+------+------+
| ID | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | VAL1 | Val2 |
| 2  | NULL | Val2 |
| 3  | VAL1 | NULL |
+----+------+------+
```

I want the query to return rows 2-3 , noting that I have many columns in actual table so I don't want to include it in the query with 'where or'.

can it be done with mysql?

Comment: do you want to avoid the first record and fetch other records?

Comment: i want to fetch all rows that contain a null column, even if i dont know the columns name :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20161429/1031945

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the best answer that does not need to hard-code the column names is:

```
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(max) = (
        SELECT stuff((
                    SELECT 'and ' + c.NAME + ' is null '
                    FROM sys.columns c
                    WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'yourtablename'
                    ORDER BY c.NAME
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 3, '')
        )

SET @sqlStr = 'select * from ' + yourtablename + ' where ' + @sqlStr

PRINT @sqlStr

EXEC (@sqlStr)
```

Comment: for next generation :)

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from tablename where col1 is NULL or col2 is NULL
```

**Result**

```
 ID | col1  | col2
 ------------------     
 2  | NULL  | Val2     
 3  | VAL1  | NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want not to use ORs, you could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE concat(col1, col2, ...) is Null
```

or this:

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE col1+col2+... is null
```

but while it's makes the query easier to write, it won't make it faster. I would suggest you just to use ORs.

Comment: This will return NULL if there is one column that is NULL. If you want to check if all columns in your list are empty use `CONCAT_WS("", col1, col2, ...)`

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(col1,0),
    IFNULL(col2,0)
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 IS NULL or col2 IS NULL
```

You can use IFNULL to set default value

Comment: i believe, this is used, when you want to fill the null column to zero :/

Comment: but, OP just need to show the related information, whose column holds NULL value, nevertheless, good effort. :)