# MYSQL IF value = null OR value = ""

Tags: mysql

I have this part of query:

```
IF(orders = NULL OR orders = '', "value1', 'value2')
```

which works with empty cells but not with null ones, any help?
When it's NULL it doesn't make anything but when it's '' it runs the query

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: selecting rows where a column is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536670/mysql-selecting-rows-where-a-column-is-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's spelled `orders is NULL` (not `orders = NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
IF(orders IS NULL OR orders = '', 'value1', 'value2')
```

instead