# Selecting rows with null in integer columns using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'datatablecoulmn' with the following columns.
[image]

now i want all rows where the column FkID is NULL.FkID  is an integer field

i tried the following queries

```
             SELECT * FROM `datatablecoulmn` WHERE `FkID`=NULL
             SELECT * FROM `datatablecoulmn` WHERE `FkID`<1
             SELECT * FROM `datatablecoulmn` WHERE `FkID`='null'
```

All of these returns empty rows .Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In MySQL, NULL is considered as a 'missing, unknown value', as opposed to no value. Any arithmetic comparison with NULL does not return true or false, but returns NULL instead., So, NULL != 'C' returns NULL, as opposed to returning true.

Use `IS NULL` condition in your query and try like this

```
SELECT * FROM `datatablecoulmn` WHERE `FkID` IS NULL
```

For handling NULL values MySQL provides three operators

> IS NULL: operator returns true if column value is NULL.
>
> IS NOT NULL: operator returns true if column value is not NULL.
>
> <=>: operator compares values, which (unlike the = operator) is true
> even for two NULL values.

You can refer to these links for more

[Link 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html),[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536670/mysql-selecting-rows-where-a-column-is-null),[Link 3](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-null-values.htm)

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is a value like infinity is a number. In other words, not at all. `NULL` is the *absence* of certain information.

Hence, for the same reason that `NaN` (not a number) in IEEE754 floating point is not equal to other instances of `NaN` (or even the *same* instance), nothing in SQL is equal to `NULL`, including `NULL`.

That's something that *may* sound strange but, when you think of the purpose of `NULL`, that of specifying unknown or inappropriate values, it makes sense. If you don't know what `A` is and you don't know what `B` is, you can't really say for certain that they're equal.

Therefore, with comparisons with `NULL`, MySQL will give you back `NULL` (unknown), as per the following transcript:

```sql
> select 1 = 1 as A, 1 = NULL as B, NULL = NULL as C, NULL is NULL as D;

A       B       C       D
1       NULL    NULL    1
```

In order to see if a value is `NULL`, you have to use `is` rather then `=`, as per the "D" case above. For your case, that would be something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `datatablecoulmn` WHERE `FkID` is NULL
```

More details on working with `NULL` in MySQL can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html).

---

And, though this isn't actually relevant to your *question*, you may want to think about the spelling of your table name (assuming it's not just a typo made when posting the question). Specifically "column" rather than "coulmn".

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare with `NULL`. So you gotta check for `YourColumn IS NULL` (or maybe `YourColumn IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `datatablecoulmn` WHERE `FkID` is NULL
```

NULL is a placeholder to say there is the absence of a value. Which is why you can only use IS NULL/IS NOT NULL as predicates for such situations and not = or != or <> which is used by values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to exclude the records with `FkID` is NOT NULL:

```
SELECT D1.*
FROM datatablecoulmn D1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT D2.* 
                  FROM datatablecoulmn D2
                  WHERE D2.`FkID` IS NOT NULL)
```