# MySql: Restricted statement that still matches all - using a wildcard?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql statement that I cannot modify. I can only throw in data:

`SELECT questionid FROM mytable WHERE tags = #`

`#` can be any data (please don't mention sql injects etc.)

My recent problem: I want to select all questionids without restriction. So what do I have to specify for `#` to ignore the tags filter.

I have just tried the `%` wildcard but it does not work.

Thanks for helping me out this early morning...

Comment: Where is the `LIKE` in your "LIKE" query?

Comment: [`WHERE tags IS NOT NULL`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536670/mysql-selecting-rows-where-a-column-is-null) is what you're really needing. You'll have to modify your code to accommodate that.

Comment: As I said I cannot modify the code, it is a core library.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because the `where` clause uses an equals sign.

Wildcards are only allowed at `like`statements.