# default null values not get selected when != conditional operator is used

Tags: mysql

I have below data with some null values present.
`flag` column has default values as `NULL`

```
test_table

Id flag
1   0
2   1
3   1
4   NULL
5   0
6   NULL
```

Now, when I write select query like

```
select Id from test_table where flag!=1
```

then it selects only data of ids 1 and 5 
actually, it should select ids 1,4,5,6

why does this happen?
whats the problem?

Comment: ` where flag!=1 OR flag is null`

Answer (score 0):

The correct query is

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE flag != 1 OR flag IS NULL
```

This is simply due to the fact that you cant use the `!=` operator (or similar ones like `==, <=, >=`, etc.) with NULL values. You need to use the `IS` operator for this. Your query will only check the rows that have a value in the flag column, since it will simply ignore the NULL values, since those will not match anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This question have already been asked and users give some good answer on this.

Please check below link:-

[MySQL: selecting rows where a column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536670/mysql-selecting-rows-where-a-column-is-null)

SQL NULL's special, and you have to do WHERE field IS NULL, as NULL cannot be equal to anything,