# Generate report condtion

Tags: report-designer

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code report problem?

=iif([INLotSerialStatus.LotSerialNbr]=NULL,(left([INLotSerialStatus.LotSerialNbr],InStr([INLotSerialStatus.LotSerialNbr],'*')),'False')

Comment: Yeah, what **is** wrong with it? Where did you type it? What did you want it to do? What other thing did it do instead? Why is this tagged `mysql` and `c` when it appears to be neither? C'mon. I'm VTC as _"Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: You could also have tried searching before posting. Comparison to `null` is a day-1 lesson of any SQL DBMS. See, e.g., [MySQL: selecting rows where a column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536670/mysql-selecting-rows-where-a-column-is-null) and many more

Comment: Sorry, my first time to post here. This is from report designer. im generating a customized report.

Answer (score 0):

NULL Can't be compare as `equal to` Use `IS NULL`

```
iif([INLotSerialStatus.LotSerialNbr] IS NULL,(left([INLotSerialStatus.LotSerialNbr],InStr([INLotSerialStatus.LotSerialNbr],'*')),'False')
```