# MySQL How to find Null data in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, null

**Scenario:** I have a table with duplicate data. One of the columns of this table is ddate, if it is empty/null I want to select that row (and remove it). But for some reason, I cannot find the null rows with a direct query.

**Issue:** When I run the following query (1):

```
select
    `ddate`, 
    count(1) as `nb`
from instrument_nt
group by `ddate`;
```

I get the number of rows where ddate is NULL and where it has other values. But when I run query (2):

```
select count(*) from instrument_nt where `ddate` =  Null;
```

or

```
select * from instrument_nt where `ddate` =  NULL;
```

My query result is either 0 or empty.

**Question:** What is the difference between those two queries (1 and 2)? How can I properly delete the data that has null/missing dates?

Comment: You should do `select * from instrument_nt where \`ddate\` IS  NULL;`

Comment: NULL does not match anything, even even NULL = NULL does not match.

Comment: `ddate =  NULL` is never TRUE. Any comparison to NULL always evaluates to NULL. You must use the `IS` operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: selecting rows where a column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536670/mysql-selecting-rows-where-a-column-is-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `NULL` mean unknow it's a value.

If you want to get `NULL` row you need to use `IS NULL` instead of eqaul `NULL`

```
select count(*) from instrument_nt where `ddate` IS  Null;
```

> What is the difference between those two queries (1 and 2)? How can I properly delete the data that has null/missing dates?

(1)

```
select count(*) from instrument_nt where `ddate` IS  Null;
```

you will get the amount `ddate` is `NULL` from `instrument_nt` table.

(2)

```
select * from instrument_nt where `ddate` IS NULL;
```

you will get a result set which `ddate` is NULL;

Comment: Spot on, I did not know that. Will accept once I can.

Answer (score 1):

Every `null` is *defined* to be different from every other `null`. Thus, equality to `null` is always `false`. See, for example, [here](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from), which describes this so-called "three value problem".

For this third class of value, you want to use `IS`, as in `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

use the keyword `IS NULL` to check the null values in tables

For example:

```
select * from instrument_nt where `ddate` IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL null checks use the `IS` operator instead of `=`.

Your query should look like this: `select * from instrument_nt where`ddate`IS NULL;`